# How to navigate a particular page by click the contents in pdf file in ios

Tags: ios, pdf, ibooks

hi every one i'm having a book as a pdf file,in this i want to Navigate to the particular page by clicking the contents of the PDF File. i.e. if i click the Chapter 4 in content means it navigate to the Chapter 4 in the Pdf.Like iBooks contents,bookmark,Notes,Help me.

Comment: Please provide more details like how you are displaying the PDF file, if you are using any third party frameworks etc...

Comment: No i didn't use any third party,i'm having one pdf file only ,i want navigate page like ibook contents

Comment: So you are not programming anything? Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check what's on topic: [help/on-topic]. If you are just an end-user and requiring help with using someone else's software, [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com) may be the place to ask.

Comment: no i already done a page curl in my pdf & now i want some idea or example to display the Contents & navigate to corresponding Page by clicking that